# Is it possible to combine 'field' and table record inside 'select' in JOOQ?

Tags: jooq, mysql-5.6

I'm using an auto incremental session variable temporary column, to get some kind of sequence for a specific sort-order. The query looks something like this:

```
return ctx.select(
            field("rowNumber"),
            TABLE.ID                
    ).from(/* Get an inner query here */)
            .where(TABLE.ID.eq(someValue))
            .orderBy(field("rowNumber").asc());
```

But, when I try to execute the above query, it returns the following error:

```
Unknown column 'TABLE.ID' in 'field list'
```

The only way I can make it work, is when `TABLE.ID` is passed as `field("ID")` inside `ctx.select()`.

Is it so that `JOOQ` doesn't support specifying the column(s) using a combination of `TableRecord` and `field("column")`?

Comment: Most likely a case sensitivity problem. Can you post the relevant bits of your subquery, as well as from the stack trace?

Comment: @LukasEder I actually managed to fix it already. Turns out, the subquery wasn't properly aliased, and that probably was why it wasn't working.

Comment: Great to hear! Thanks for documenting your solution here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it is possible to do so. Apparently, the improper aliasing might have had something to do with the issue. Solved it like this:

```
TABLE t = TABLE.as("t");
return ctx.select(
            field("rowNumber"),
            t.ID                
    ).from(getInnerQuery().asTable("t"))
            .where(t.ID.eq(someValue))
            .orderBy(field("rowNumber").asc());
```